# Changing FlatList renderItem prop via onViewableItemsChanged

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to pass dynamic value to property `visible` to each item of `FlatList` if they are inside the viewport, thus value of this prop changes on scroll, but I am getting a bit laggy scrolling experience (items are changing positions on every rerender, something like jumping up and down).

How can I avoid it?

my code looks like

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import {FlatList} from 'react-native';

const TabOne = ({ data, ...rest }) => {
    const [visibleIdx, setVisibleIdx] = useState(null);

    const onViewableItemsChanged = useRef(({ changed }) => {
        setVisibleIdx(changed.length ? changed[0].item.id : null);
    });

    const renderItem = (item) => (
        <ContentItem isVisible={item.id === visibleIdx} />
    );

    return (
        <FlatList
            data={data}
            viewabilityConfig={{ viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 75 }}
            onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged.current}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => renderItem(item, index)}
            {...rest}
        />
    );
};

export default TabOne;
```